# Count number of times a value appears (and append it in EVERY row) in R

Tags: r

so I want to count the number of times each value appears in a vector and to create a new vector, of EQUAL length, to bind it with the initial one. So my solution cannot be the *table* function as it returns only the unique values and the times they appear. I need in **each** row of the initial vector to append its number of appearences. I have found a solution but I got a big database with ~800k rows and it runs for like 10 min. Does anyone know how to perform this task more efficiently? I include an example.Thanks

```
df<-as.data.frame(sample(1:100, 800000, replace = T))
df[2]<-rep(1,nrow(df))
names(df)<-c("Numbers","Count")

df$Count<-pbapply(df,1,function(x) length(which(df$Numbers==df$Numbers[x])))
```

P.S. I have used to *pbapply* function to keep track of the progress.

Comment: Please provide a toy example and include your expected output. The desired output is not clear to me from the text (probably due to a caffeine deficiency). Also, mention the package that `pbapply` comes from as it is not part of base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do the trick:

```
df<-data.frame(Numbers=sample(1:100, 800000, replace = T))

Count <- ddply(df, .(Numbers), summarize, Count=length(Numbers)) #Unique values and how many times they appear

Indices<-match(df$Numbers, Count$Numbers) #Use match to add counts to data frame
df$Count <- Count$Count[Indices]
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for and it runs in under 1 sec! Perfect!

Comment: To be honest, Craig's solution is right as well. I just preferred this one. Thanks to both!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a count of the number of each unique item in `Number`, this is straightforward in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(123)
df<-data.frame(Numbers = sample(1:100, 800000, replace = T))
df2 <- df %>%
  group_by(Numbers) %>%
  mutate(Count = n())
head(df2)

# Numbers Count
# 51      8146
# 49      7961
# 3       8090
# 63      8072
# 80      8017
# 80      8017
```